# Merging memberships issue

Tags: civimember, duplicate-contacts

When I merge two contact together and each contact has a membership, I need to tick the 'add new' box to keep both memberships. Otherwise one of the memberships is deleted.

However one membership reads Member since 01/01/2000. Membership Ends 01/01/2016.

The other membership reads Member Since 01/01/2016. Membership Ends 01/01/2017.

Now clearly its a renewal so I want just one membership that reads Member since 01/01/2000. Membership Ends 01/01/2017.

How can I do this without manually changing one membership and manually deleting the other.

The merge membership deletes one membership but does not amend the membership to the new dates.

Many thanks,

Andy
CIVICRM 4.5.8
Drupal

Comment: You need to remember the feature is "merge CONTACTS" not "merge memberships"  I don't believe there is a way to merge memberships through the UI.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, CiviCRM can’t do this natively, as you can see in that [question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/799). I’m facing the same problem, I will *try* to solve it by doing an extension.

### Update (2017-11-20)

I’ve started to work on a patch for CiviCRM. [The work-in-progress PR is available here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11298). Comments are welcome ;)

Olivier;