# Membership issues when people have two different emails

Tags: civimember, duplicate-contacts, renewals

Given how difficult it is to merge two contacts, each with memberships (as detailed in
[How can I merge two memberships in the same contact (without losing contribution info, etc)?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/799/how-can-i-merge-two-memberships-in-the-same-contact-without-losing-contribution)) we are anxious to avoid this situation when members renew.  But how?

Contacts who are already members but have a new email address since joining will try to renew with the new email address.  Their name is the same, but a new contact record gets created and their new membership goes into that contact.

Our membership renewal reminder emails contain a link that will let them renew properly, but we can't FORCE users to only use that link.  Ideally members could ask us to change their email address first, THEN renew.  But we can't force them to do that either.

Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: can you confirm whether you are sending out Scheduled Reminders with a checksum link - and hence is the problem when folk use this, and then want to update their email, and if this then causes problems with the Matching Rule not behaving correctly? Assumption (could be wrong) is that if you have cid + checksum in the url then the matching rule is disabled and hence they would be able to update their email without creating a duplicate even if the email is a required element of the matching rule

2/ user clicks link and arrives at pre-filled form to renew their membership

Comment: Well, the reminder contains the link:

ourdomain.com/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=2&{contact.checksum}&cid={contact.contact_id}

Is that wrong?  Do I want the matching rule disabled?  How do I control that?

Comment: let me check this